# MySQL PHP query always returning 1

Tags: php, mysql

This script always returns one, not the actual number of online users. Can anyone help fix my code?

```
$oq = "SELECT user FROM user_archive WHERE time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";
$oresult = mysqli_query($con,$oq);
$online_users = mysqli_num_rows($oresult);

if($online_users = 1)
{
     echo "{$online_users} user online";    
}

if($online_users != 1)
{
echo "{$online_users} users online";    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `==` instead of `=`

```
if($online_users == 1)
{
     echo "{$online_users} user online";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line of code where you wrote:

if($online_users = 1)

You are asigning the value 1 to $online_users, instead of comparing the value. It should be:

if($online_users == 1)

Answer (score 1):

Using one equals sign is something called an `assignment operator` so:

```
$Var = 1; // This variable equals to 1
```

But when validating.

```
if ($Var == 1){

} // Notice the use of two equals, for a comparison operator
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

`$online_users = 1` must be `$online_users == 1`.

And

```
$oq = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_archive WHERE time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";
```

or

```
$oq = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) FROM user_archive WHERE time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";
```

`COUNT(*)` counts, not what you do.

**Why retrieve `rows of data` to counts them when you can just get one `integer` back and get MySql to count for you?**

Comment: So, I am just a big derp. XD

Comment: @Grace You're more like a performance hog/menace :) One that risks to download `hundreds/thousands of rows` just for one `integer`.

Comment: I was just confused. I had no rows, and nothing was happening to the integer. XD